# Custom taxonomy not refreshing page on add

Tags: functions, tags

I have created a custom taxonomy for use with WP Job Manager. The taxonomy shows up, however when I type in my tag and click the "add new job title" button nothing seems to happen. If I click refresh I can see that in fact the tag has been added.

I think my question is similar to [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/171982/quick-edit-selected-custom-taxonomy-not-refreshing-after-save) and [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66583/fields-dont-reflect-previous-quick-edit-changes-when-clicking-quick-edit-a-seco). However I can not be sure because I am not entirely sure.

This is the the code:

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function ikana_jobtitle() {

       $labels = array(
            'name'                       => _x( 'Job Titles', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
            'singular_name'              => _x( 'Job Title', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
            'menu_name'                  => __( 'Job Titles', 'text_domain' ),
            'all_items'                  => __( 'All Job titles', 'text_domain' ),
            'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Job titles', 'text_domain' ),
            'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Job:', 'text_domain' ),
            'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Job Title', 'text_domain' ),
            'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Job Title', 'text_domain' ),
            'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Job Title', 'text_domain' ),
            'update_item'                => __( 'Update Job Title', 'text_domain' ),
            'view_item'                  => __( 'View Job Title', 'text_domain' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate titles with commas', 'text_domain' ),
            'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove titles', 'text_domain' ),
            'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used Job Titles', 'text_domain' ),
            'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Job Titles', 'text_domain' ),
            'search_items'               => __( 'Search Job Titles', 'text_domain' ),
            'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
            'labels'                     => $labels,
            'hierarchical'               => false,
            'public'                     => true,
            'show_ui'                    => true,
            'show_admin_column'          => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
            'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'jobtitle', array( 'post', ' job_listing', ' resume'     ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'ikana_jobtitle', 0 );

}
```

Comment: You are not sure what they ask in the linked questions and I'm not sure what you are asking here. The taxonomy shows up, where? Which page is not refreshing? Which tab you are typing in? Which "add" button are you clicking?

Comment: Under posts is the only place it currently showes up as "Job Title". When I type in say "Driver" and click "Add New Job Title" Nothing happens. If I refresh the page, "driver" will have been added. Further more when I delete an item I see the item flash red then get "An unidentified error has occurred" and nothing happens but again if I refresh that item will be gone. This happened before and we went through typical troubleshooting and I thought disabling a particular plugin fixed the problem, but that plugin is still disabled and the problem has returned right after creating this new taxonomy

Comment: Sounds like a JavaScript error. Best options would be to deactivate all plugins and see if error still happens, and if not, then re-activate plugins one by one and test adding after activating each plugin. You can also check your browser console and see if an error is showing up there.

Comment: It took a few tries but narrowed it down to buddypress. I have posted a support request on their site and will update this when I find more info.

Comment: BuddyPress says it is not them, however disabling their plugin fixes the problem. I hope this can help someone in the future but their support has been a dead end.